# How to make a flask app be multi-processing?

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, webserver

This is my code

```
class Time :
@app.route('/time', methods = ['GET'])
def get() :     
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(30000) :
        for j in range(30000) :
            pass
    return str(time.time() - start)
```

I have tried many tools to solve it, such as tornado, gunicorn and python's multi-thread and multi-processing, but all failed.Once I open the web localhost:5000/time, the time I open two webs simultaneous is much slower than I open a web two times.

In my opinion, if I accomplish the multi-processing, the time should be half.

Edit:

this code is used to build a multi-processing app by tornado

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and if I open a web two times, it will cost 23s, but if I open two webs at the same time, it will cost 26s. I hope it can cost 11s, equal to I open a web.

Comment: What `multiprocessing` code did you try and what specifically happened when you tried it?

Comment: thanks for your response, and I update my question now. the code-style in comment is really ugly so I put it in my question.

Comment: why do you need it to be multiprocessed? For background tasks or something? 
Doesnt Flask spin up more app instances with threads already?

Comment: thanks for your response, I just want to practice it. I 'm a flask learner and I want to  learn about multi-processing. Flask has a multi-thread method but the Python GIL make it become a fake multi-processing, and the program result just like what I have said in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up a bit.

Gunicorn is used to build dynamic API in a more efficient way, and typically you should use it in pair with nginx to actually gain in efficiency. I.e. Gunicorn to build dynamic APIs and nginx to redistribute the static ones.

You can read here in more details
https://serverfault.com/questions/331256/why-do-i-need-nginx-and-something-like-gunicorn

Here is working Gunicorn setup:

```
echo "--------------- Kill workers ---------------"
ps aux | grep gunicorn | grep myniceappname | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9
echo "--------------- Start workers ---------------"
gunicorn run:app --name myniceappname --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 4 --reload
```

Comment: thanks a lot! So the key to multi-processing is nginx, right?

Comment: Actually, both, Gunicorn and nginx. You static requests will come to nginx and will be redistributed in a fast and efficient way. But nginx doesn't know how to build dynamic APIs, for example how to convert @app.route('/<some_place>') into localhost:5000/stanford, so for this nginx should redirect to Gunicorn. Often mistake is to use Gunicorn for all purposes -  for redistribution and for dynamic APIs, this way your production server will have performance issues.

Comment: thank you very much! with your help I think i realize it much more.

Comment: so if i want to build a multi-processing program, i need nginx to redistribute and gunicorn to connect it with my program.